# Spring Cloud DataFlow for HTTP request/response exchange

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I would like to use streams to handle an HTTP request/response exchange. I didn't see any Spring Cloud Stream App Starters with HTTP sink functionality. Will I need to build a custom sink to handle the response? If so, do I pass the request through my processing pipeline, then use the request in my sink to form the response? I don't think I've misunderstood the use case of Spring Cloud DataFlow and Spring Cloud Stream. Perhaps there are app starters available for this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream/Dataflow is for unidirectional (stream) processing; it is not intended for request/reply processing.

You could, however, utilize a Stream from a Spring Integration Application; for example, with the rabbitmq binder...

```
http-inbound-gateway -> amqp-outbound-gateway
```

Where the outbound gateway is configured to expect the reply from a specific queue and then your stream could be...

```
:requestQueue > processor1 | ... | processorn > :replyQueue
```

Spring Integration doesn't currently have an outbound gateway for Kafka. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/issues/161).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, Gary. The HTTP to MySQL Demo in the spring-cloud-data-flow-samples repository is very close to what I have in mind, but if there was a validation error, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to notify the requester that something went wrong.

Comment: It's not really "close" because it's a unidirectional pipeline. As I said, you'd need to invoke the stream from a gateway in order to get a reply; to handle errors, each stage in the pipeline would have to be configured to send exceptions to the "reply" channel. Right now that would need some coding; we're working on improving the error handling story.