# Spring-Cloud-flow orchestration for realtime data processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I need to build a orchestration layer for couple of Rest APIs (microservices), message based services and post the result to a messaging layer (RabbitMQ/Kafka). Our application is realtime similar to loan processing. Customer provide some details via UI and wait for the response. I am looking at the Spring-cloud-Dataflow to build the orchestration.

**High level requirements**

- Need a flexible orchestration layer to add/remove more APIs, services in future quickly (minimal coding is preferred)
- Should be able to track state of the request
- Deployable in AWS runtime
- Scalable and fault tolerant

[image]

As per this link [SCDF for request-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307078/spring-cloud-dataflow-for-http-request-response-exchange) SCDf is not built for request and response model.Lets say if architect my application to not wait for the response.

1. Can I use the SpringCloud DataFlow for the realtime applications like loan processing?
2. Do you have any examples for AWS runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) supports composition of messaging-based streaming microservices and the ability to orchestrate short-lived task/batch microservices that run for a finite period.

However, in the next major release, we will have support for traditional REST based applications as well. With streaming, task/batch, and REST applications all of them consistently built as Spring Boot apps and the orchestration mechanics such as grouping-of-apps, versioning, and data-pipeline-edits provided by SCDF; you'll be able to build the types of topologies that you've in the visual more easily.

That said,

> Can I use the SpringCloud DataFlow for the realtime applications like loan processing?

To solution this, you could build the applications using Spring Cloud Stream. There's dynamic destination handler support in the recent [Chelsea release](https://spring.io/blog/2017/03/16/spring-cloud-stream-chelsea-rc1-released#dispatching-capabilities-added-to-streamlistener), which would allow you to pin and route to a particular downstream event handler automatically - see [this blog](https://dturanski.wordpress.com/) for more details. Once you have this type of applications, they can be registered in SCDF to build coherent data pipelines with it.

> Do you have any examples for AWS runtime?

You can review the available/supported implementations from the [project site](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#spring-cloud-data-flow-implementations). We do not have any plans for AWS proper - contributions welcome.